# Oracle SQL, combine 2 columns, each column contains text with new line (chr(10)) delimiters

Tags: sql, oracle11g

[image]

what I am hoping to accomplish is to combine change_date and change_history into one column where it looks like

```
20-Sep-17 : NULL to 

16-Oct-17 : NULL to 2017-10-18
```

but what I am getting is

```
20-Sep-17

16-Oct-17:NULL to NULL to 2017-10-18
```

Any ideas? Here are some of my own.

First one:

```
SELECT ORDER
, RN
, (SELECT LISTAGG(CHANGE_DATE || ':' || COALESCE(CHANGE_HISTORY, ' '), ' ')
     WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CHANGE_DATE) FROM DUAL) AS NEW_CHANGE_COLUMN
FROM VERY_LARGE_WITH_STATEMENT;
```

Query to reproduce raw data:

```
SELECT '2466495'
     , '0'
     , '20-Sep-17' || CHR(10) || '16-Oct-17'
     , 'NULL to ' || CHR(10) || 'NULL to 2017-10-18'
  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '2776608'
     , '1'
     , '11-Dec-17' || CHR(10) || '19-Dec-17' || CHR(10) || '30-Dec-17'
     ,    'NULL to 13-DEC-17 '
       || CHR(10)
       || '2017-12-13 to 2017-12-20'
       || CHR(10)
       || '2017-12-20 to 2017-12-30 '
  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '3014275'
     , '2'
     , NULL
     , NULL
  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '3236553'
     , '3'
     , '12-Mar-18'
     , 'NULL to 14-MAR-18'
  FROM DUAL
```

Comment: why are you using LISTAGG here? - thats whats messing you up

Comment: many attempts with many different ideas, that was the latest.

Comment: can you create a query that returns the data exactly how you have it in the excel above?

Comment: @DanielMarcus not sure if the 'new lines' are still intact after i copied/pasted it.

Comment: not sure what you mean by that - if you can post the query that returns the data in your excel above BEFORE concatenation, I can get the concatenation to work correctly for you

Comment: added the select to create the table

Comment: still not really following you - what you need to do is create a select without any concatenation - then wrap the select up and concatenate from there - i will try to demonstrate below

Comment: Can you create SQL fiddle with some data?

Answer (score 0):

```
select field1, field2||field3, etc... from 
(select your query without concatenation)a
where...
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to produce precisely what you had asked for:

```
WITH very_large_with_statement as (
select '2466495' as "ORDER", '0' RN, '20-Sep-17' CHANGE_DATE,'NULL to' as CHANGE_HISTORY  from dual union all  
SELECT '','' ,'16-Oct-17' ,'NULL to 2017-10-18'   from dual union all     
select '2776608', '1', '11-Dec-17','NULL to 13-DEC-17' from dual union all    
select '','','19-Dec-17','2017-12-13 to 2017-12-20' from dual union all
select '','','30-Dec-17','2017-12-20  to 2017-12-30'  from dual union all
select '3014275', '2', null, null from dual union all 
select '3236553', '3', '12-Mar-18', 'NULL to 14-MAR-18' from dual
)
SELECT "ORDER"
, RN
, (SELECT LISTAGG(CHANGE_DATE || decode(change_date,null,'',':') || COALESCE(CHANGE_HISTORY, ' '), ' ')
     WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CHANGE_DATE) FROM DUAL) AS NEW_CHANGE_COLUMN
FROM VERY_LARGE_WITH_STATEMENT;
```

and it produced this result in Oracle SQL Developer:

[image]

Comment: thank you, but...  change_date and change_history, if they have multiple values they are separated by chr(10).  the select you are using is setting them up in their own row.  I cannot do that with my data.

Comment: I need to see examples where the change_date is repeated and new change_history is concatenated...your initial input data example did not show this.

Comment: I added query to reproduce the raw data

Answer (score 0):

After rethinking the problem, I concatenated first then aggregated the list. 
Thought I'd post because sometimes the solution is to rethink.

```
WITH TEST
 AS (SELECT CHANGE_DATE
          , CHANGE_DATE || ' : '
            || REGEXP_REPLACE(
                  REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(CHANGE_DESCRIPTION
                                             , 'NEED_DATE:.*$'
                                             , 1
                                             , 1
                                             , 'm')  -- to end of line as there was additional unwanted text 
                               , 'NEED_DATE:'  -- removes what i searched for
                               , '')
                , '\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d'  -- removes timestamp from date
                , '')
               AS COMBINED_HISTORY
       FROM REF_CHANGE_HISTORY R
      WHERE INSTR(CHANGE_DESCRIPTION
                , '-NEED_DATE:'
                , 1) > 0
        AND R.RN = 3881217
     ORDER BY CHANGE_DATE)
SELECT LISTAGG(COMBINED_HISTORY
         , CHR(10))
   WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COMBINED_HISTORY)
 FROM TEST
```